# Similar package or any solution to Liquid floating action button in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Please look at [LiquidFloatingActionButton](https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton). It's well-known animation in ios app.

I need to make similar animation in Xamarin forms project.
Here is what I want to create.
[image]

I've searched but couldn't find anyone.

Any suggestion will be helped!
Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Its not very clear what you want.

If it is just animations then Lottie is a good way to go

https://blog.xamarin.com/bring-stunning-animations-to-your-apps-with-lottie/

If you are looking for a floating action button then there is one here that works on both Android and iOS.

https://github.com/SuavePirate/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.FloatingActionButton

If you want exactly the same button behaving in exactly the same way you will have to create your own custom control and use it to wrap the LiquidFloatingActionButton.

EDIT

Now you have changed your question, you can achieve that using the standard built in animation system

[Details here](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-animations-with-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: So what I want is to show clickable 2 buttons with animation when click one button. The animation is similar to liquid floating button animation.

Comment: The only way you could do this with exactly the same animation is to create your own custom renderer in ios and to wrap the LiquidFloatingActionButton inside it.

Comment: then how to implement in android?

Comment: You need to find a native implementation of LiquidFloatingActionButton for Android and then create a custom renderer there as well.

Comment: Please look at my updated question. I attached what I am going to create. Thanks for help

Comment: Updated answer. Try and avoid completely changing your question. it is frowned upon on SO.